# Game Development with Accomplishments

Tags: games, accomplishments

Hey could game developers make accomplishments for game players to earn forever who buys games from the Ubuntu Software Center?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create accomplishments for games. From [The Guide to Creating Your Accomplishments](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Accomplishments/Creating/Guide) (emphasis added):

> Q: Why would I want to create accomplishments?
>
> ...
>
> - Because you want a new application to be supported by Accomplishments System **(for example: a new game)**.
> - Because you want to create a new collection of accomplishments designed for your community.

See the [Accomplishments wiki/documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Accomplishments) for more details, including how the accomplishments system recognises an accomplishment as being acheived (you write a Python script for each accomplishment). Note that most of the [guidelines](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Accomplishments/Creating/Guidelines) and [ideas](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Accomplishments/AccomplishmentIdeas) are centered around learning how to use Ubuntu rather than games.